# CoreData optional to-many relationships can never be nil?

Tags: core-data, one-to-many, relationship, nsmanagedobject, null

Quirk I just discovered, and wanted to confirm with anyone here whether or not this is avoidable. Basically, if I have a very simple two entity model:

[image]

With a to-many relationship between `Entity1` and `Entity2`. The relationship is optional, with nullify as the delete rule on both sides. However, if I insert a new `Entity1` the value of the `children` relationship will be an empty set, not `nil`:

```
NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription
                           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity1"
                           inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
assert([object valueForKey:@"children"] != nil);
```

Furthermore, I can't explicitly set the relationship to `nil`:

```
[object setValue:nil forKey:@"children"];
assert([object valueForKey:@"children"] != nil);
```

I have verified this in a new, minimal project and this appears to be a true implementation detail. The problem is, I would like to be able to differentiate between a `nil` value (representing currently unknown) and an empty set (truly a to-zero relationship). Does CoreData actually support this at all in a reasonably direct manner? Currently it seems not, which means I will have to find another (less direct) way to represent my model.

Thanks,

J

Comment: Note I've also verified this with `-primitiveValueForKey:`; the result is the same

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer is no.  You will always get an empty set back.  If you need to know if an object structure is fully realized (my guess at what your goal is) then you would want to set an attribute on the object to say if it is fully realized or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, seems I'll have to find another way to represent this other than relying on `nil`.